# Can't measure torque with ft sensor

Tags: gazebo-11, gazebo-sensor

I am simulating in Gazebo-classic (Gazebo 11) a simple scenario with a single link (a box) linked to the world with a revolute joint having axis along z.
I followed the [force-torque sensor](https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=force_torque_sensor&cat=sensors) tutorial and I have placed a sensor in the joint in order to get a torque feedback. However, despite manually applyng a torque to the box around z axis using the GUI utility, the torque the sensor is reading is always 0. I have also tried applying a torque through a plugin (using 'AddRelativeTorque'), but the result is the same.
In both cases the box is spinning thus a torque is present indeed.